# How To Choose And Create a Icon?

Tags: icons, appearance

As I develop some things to my self and now I'm developing some of this applications for my friends and my family. I want to put icons on this applications, because It's takes the appearance better, but how to choose a icon that will combine better with your application and what is the best programs to develop some professional icons?

Comment: It kind of depends on the language and tools you are using. Are you using C# and Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and developing using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this software: http://icofx.ro/

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio comes with a lot of stock icons that will at least make your apps look "Windows-y".

Look around:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\1033
```

for a file called:

```
VS2008ImageLibrary.zip
```

In it, you will find a variety of standard icons.

Answer (score 1):

With IcoFX you can select part of an image to create an icon.  Here's their tutorial for more on the subject http://icofx.ro/tutorials/tutorial1.html.  It's a good free icon editor.